# Why do SIMD CPU extensions exist?

Tags: cpu, performance, gpu, cpu-architecture, parallel-processing

As I understand the problem there are problems that can be heavily parallelized, e.g. rendering, video decoding. Since CPUs are not excelling in such tasks GPU were created. They use different architectures to employ SIMD execution. They also have a special type of memory that works well for independent access to GPU "threads".

However, what we see is that the x86 architecture receives numerous extensions that focus on streaming processing, such as SSE or AVX. They are also SIMD, and for some reason run on the CPU side. So what is the point of adding them?

- What kind of advantage do these extensions give over a regular GPU? I mean GPUs have higher memory bandwidth and other, but doesn't it put CPUs with extensions at a disadvantage? Don't they suffer from memory bandwidth issues?
- I understand that not every computer should have a dedicated GPU, e.g. servers or workstations. But if the payload is small, it should not be an issue. And if the payload is big enough, you would buy a graphics card for that task. SIMD extensions are like a middleground between CPU and GPU.
- If SIMD extensions make CPU more capable of performing tasks that are usually performed by GPU doesn't it make GPU more obsolete? I mean if they can make CPU more SIMD friendly why didn't they make it in the first place and decide to outsource this problem to a different device?

I just want to know that applications these extenstions receive in a software where performance matters. For example, a game engine or a renderer would certainly use a GPU, would SIMD extensions make a difference?

Comment: [What is the benefit of SIMD on a superscalar out-of-order CPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42793823/995714)

Comment: Time to dive into history! Back when SIMD instructions for CPUs were first introduced, GPGPU was not a thing.

Comment: @DanielB: Indeed. There is a gap of 37 years, in fact!!! The first CPU with SIMD instructions was in 1966. GPGPU didn't become a thing until the 2000s. Floating point support and programmable shaders didn't appear until 2001, but it took until 2003 until someone first implemented a general-purpose algorithm on a GPU that actually ran faster than on a CPU. What were people supposed to do in the 37 years in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you can do something on a GPU doesn't mean that doing it on a GPU is the best place to do it.

GPUs work best when you have large amounts of data that requires the same operations run across it. For smaller batches of data it may well be more efficient to run it inline with CPU code.

One of the problems with GPUs is that it requires a CPU to take data from somewhere, load it into RAM, copy it across the PCIe bus, load up a program on the GPU to process the data, run that program and them copy the results back to the CPU RAM. Only after all that work can the CPU do something with the data.

If your CPU has a set of instructions that are geared towards that kind of operation and doesn't need to do all that work of setting up the GPU, then you may well find that for small amounts of data that the CPU is actually faster.

This is especially true where the data is tightly dependent on a CPU control structure or the data is particularly short lived.

If it takes a CPU only 0.1 seconds to do an [SHA hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) using SSE or AVX, is it really worth spending 0.1 seconds sending data to the GPU, another 0.25 seconds compiling a shader program for that specific GPU, and waiting for your data to come back?

When you're hungry and need something right now do you order food online and wait for it or do you just grab something from your already stocked up fridge?

Comment: As someone whose fridge once broke right at the beginning of a long weekend + bank holiday, I can totally relate to your example :-D